# How to let the user know that a graph do contain drill down in power bi?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

Is it possible to show a subtitle in a power bi graph? I want to show the user that, this specific graph does contain drill-down(like the below-attached[image: subtitle] image).

If I add a hardcoded text box it is overlapping with the graph. Is there any way to show that the particular graph contains drill-down(like if I hove on the graph title, It should this contains drill-down)
Please suggest some ideas.

Comment: You can use the new drill down buttons functionality, so if there is a button you can drill down, or let the visual header only show the drill down option. Sub titles are not available in the standard PBI Visuals

Answer (score 0):

Usually, if drill-down is available, it shows some navigation buttons on the top right of the graph, which is basically is an indicator that drill-down is available:

[Navigation buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTjF3.png)

Another option, which I personally do not like, but that might work for you. You can create a measure which just displays some help text like "Drilldown is available" and you can place it to the "Tooltips" section of the graph. When user hovers the mouse over the graph data, he will see the tooltip with this text. Something like this:

[Tooltips](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrpCD.png)

Comment: Yes, it shows "Navigation Buttons" on hover but the requirement is to show some additional text so that by looking at the dashboard some can directly identify. Is it possible to show custom tooltip only while hovering on graph title?

Comment: @Sidhartha There are no such tooltips, unfortunately. I have tested one workaround which might work for you. You can specifu measure as a title name, so, 3 steps to be done:

1. Create a measure which just includes text with a new row like that:

Measure = "This is the title
This is the subtitle"

2. In graph settings, go to Title and press fx button next to the "title text"
3. Select Format By: "Field Value" and Based On Field: this new measure

As a result you will have two rows in the graph title.

Comment: I am already using a measure for the tile of the graph.